# Appending a new row inside the populated table using form-repeater takes a huge time (10-15s) - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-plugins

**I am using form-repeater plugin for a table element. After populating the table and when i click on the plus button (add new row) it takes an huge amount of time (around 10-15 secs) for the new row to get appended.**

> Screenshot of my table

[image: Screenshot of my table]

*On every click (plus button) The below functions are executed*

- CheckEmptyInputs()
- CheckDuplicateRanges() : This checks for duplicate ranges in Min-Range and Max-Range.

Things that i have tried:

- Add a class named **" completed "** to all rows on each successfull click of the plus button after validating. I did this because when i click the plus button again i tell JS to not check the rows with class **" completed "** inorder to avoid unnecessary checking.
- I remove the class **" completed "** OnDOMSubtreeModified for the tr. So this plan works fine and JS doesn't check for these rows with class named completed every time unless the class is removed.
- I tried checking which function is taking a lot of time and as a result the checkEmptyInputs() and CheckDuplicateRanges() executed much faster.

> **NOTE - 1 :** I am using summernote extremely customized for the Min-Max-Range-Columns.
>   **NOTE - 2 :** I am using select2 plugin for the dropdownlist Columns.

Hence from my opinion the time lag may be due to the following reasons

1. Initializing of the summernote and select2 plugins for these 6 columns
2. May be there is something wrong with the form-repeater code. ***I didn't check the form-repeater code***

### **Here is my current code.**

**The HTML code for the plus buttons(dummy and original):**

```
<td colspan="2">
        <button data-repeater-create type="button" class="btn btn-gradient- 
            info btn-sm icon-btn ml-2 mb-2" id="btnaddnewroworiginal" 
            style="display:none;">
                <i class="mdi mdi-plus"></i>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-gradient-info btn-sm icon-btn 
            ml-2 mb-2 btnaddnewrowdummy" data-toggle="tooltip" data- 
            placement="top" title="Add new row">
            <i class="mdi mdi-plus"></i>
        </button>
</td>
```

**The plus button click event :**

```
    $(document).on("click", ".btnaddnewrowdummy", function () {
            var EmptyInputs = CheckEmptyInputs();
            if (EmptyInputs > 0) {
                alert("Empty Inputs Found. Please fill all the required (*) values.");
            }
            else {
                var DuplicateRangeValues = CheckDuplicateRanges();
                if (DuplicateRangeValues > 0) {
                    alert("Duplicate Max-Range values found. Please enter unique values.");
                }
                else {
                    $("#SubCategoryTable tr").each(function () {
                        $(this).addClass("completed");
                    });
                    $("#btnaddnewroworiginal").click();
                    $("#SubCategoryTable tr:last").find('.txtname').val('');
                    $("#SubCategoryTable tr:last").find(".txtminage").val("0");
                    $("#SubCategoryTable tr:last").find(".txtmaxage").val("99");
                    $("#SubCategoryTable tr:last").find('.js-example-basic-single').select2({
                        escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
                            return markup;
                        }
                    });
                    $("#SubCategoryTable tr:last").find(".js-example-basic-single-2").select2();
                    $("#SubCategoryTable tr:last").find(".summernote").summernote({
                        toolbar: [],
                        height: 50,
                        minHeight: 50,
                        maxHeight: 50,
                        disableResizeEditoroption: true
                    });
                    $("#SubCategoryTable tr:last").find(".summernote").each(function () {
                        $(this).summernote('code', '');
                    });
                    $("#SubCategoryTable tr:last").find('.note-editable').off();
                    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
                    $("#SubCategoryTable tr:last").find(".txtsubheading").val($("#SubCategoryTable tr:last").prev("tr").find(".txtsubheading").val().trim());
                    $("#SubCategoryTable tr:last").find(".ddlItemFor").val($("#SubCategoryTable tr:last").prev("tr").find(".ddlItemFor").val()).trigger("change");
                    if ($("#SubCategoryTable tr:last").prev("tr").find(".txtsubheading").val().trim() != "") {
                        $("#SubCategoryTable tr:last").find(".selectUnits").val($("#SubCategoryTable tr:last").prev("tr").find(".selectUnits").val()).trigger("change");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

**The CheckEmptyInputs function :**

```
function CheckEmptyInputs() {
            var empty_count = 0;
            $("#SubCategoryTable tr").each(function () {
                var row = $(this);
                if ($(row).hasClass("completed") == false) {
                    var name = row.find("td").find(".txtname").val();
                    if (name.trim() == "") {
                        empty_count++;
                    }
                    var UnitsVal = row.find("td").find(".selectUnits").val();
                    if (UnitsVal == 0) {
                        empty_count++;
                    }
                    var minage = row.find("td").find(".txtminage").val();
                    if (minage.trim() == "") {
                        empty_count++;
                    }
                    var maxage = row.find("td").find(".txtmaxage").val();
                    if (maxage.trim() == "") {
                        empty_count++;
                    }
                    var minmalerange = row.find("td").find(".txtminmalerange").summernote("code");
                    if (minmalerange.trim() == "") {
                        empty_count++;
                    }

                    var minfemalerange = row.find("td").find(".txtminfemalerange").summernote("code");
                    if (minfemalerange.trim() == "") {
                        empty_count++;
                    }
                }
            });
            return empty_count;
        }
```

**The CheckDuplicateRanges function :**

```
function CheckDuplicateRanges() {
            var MinMaleRange = "";
            var MaxMaleRange = "";
            var MinFemaleRange = "";
            var MaxFemaleRange = "";
            var DuplicateCount = 0;
            $("#SubCategoryTable tr").each(function () {
                var row = $(this);
                if ($(row).hasClass("completed") == false) {
                    MinMaleRange = row.find("td").find(".txtminmalerange").summernote("code").replace(/&nbsp;/g, '').replace(/<br\s*[\/]?>/gi, '').replace(/\s/g, '');
                    MaxMaleRange = row.find("td").find(".txtmaxmalerange").summernote("code").replace(/&nbsp;/g, '').replace(/<br\s*[\/]?>/gi, '').replace(/\s/g, '');
                    if (MinMaleRange == MaxMaleRange) {
                        DuplicateCount++;
                        row.find("td").find(".txtmaxmalerange").next().css("border-color", "red");
                    }
                    else {
                        row.find("td").find(".txtmaxmalerange").next().css("border-color", "#ebedf2");
                    }

                    MinFemaleRange = row.find("td").find(".txtminfemalerange").summernote("code").replace(/&nbsp;/g, '').replace(/<br\s*[\/]?>/gi, '').replace(/\s/g, '');
                    MaxFemaleRange = row.find("td").find(".txtmaxfemalerange").summernote("code").replace(/&nbsp;/g, '').replace(/<br\s*[\/]?>/gi, '').replace(/\s/g, '');
                    if (MinFemaleRange == MaxFemaleRange) {
                        DuplicateCount++;
                        row.find("td").find(".txtmaxfemalerange").next().css("border-color", "red");
                    }
                    else {
                        row.find("td").find(".txtmaxfemalerange").next().css("border-color", "#ebedf2");
                    }
                }
            });
            return DuplicateCount;
        }
```

**The form-repeater code:**

```
(function($) {
    'use strict';
    $(function() {
         $('.repeater').repeater({
                defaultValues: {
                    'text-input': 'foo'
                },
             show: function () {
                 $(this).slideDown();
                 // I wonder if there is a problem with .not()
                 $('#tblRepeater>tbody>tr').not(':first').each(function () {
                     var select = $(this).closest('tr').find(".drpUnits");
                     $(this).closest('tr').find(".drpUnits").addClass('js-example-basic-double');
                     // I think this line here is unnecessary as it is 
                     // initialized in my code ??
                     $('.js-example-basic-double').select2();
                 });
                },
             hide: function (deleteElement) {
                 if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row ?. Once deleted data cannot be retrieved.")) {
                     $(this).slideUp(deleteElement);
                 }
                 else {
                 }  
                },
             isFirstItemUndeletable: false
            })
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the solution for my problem. All i did was I hid these lines as expected to do from the form-repeater js code. Because these lines were repeatedly re-initializing all the rows inside $.each for all rows every time i clicked the plus button.

***My solution:***  *I hid those four lines from the form-repeater which drastically reduced the time lag from 15-20 seconds to 1-2 seconds*

```
              show: function () {
                 $(this).slideDown();
                 //$('#tblRepeater>tbody>tr').not(':first').each(function () {
                     //var select = $(this).closest('tr').find(".drpUnits");
                     //$(this).closest('tr').find(".drpUnits").addClass('js-example-basic-double');
                     //$('.js-example-basic-double').select2();
                 //});
                },
```